# Is $\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to a polynomial ring over a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, smith-normal-form

I'm a little bit puzzled. So Wikipedia says that the Smith normal form applies to matrices with entries in a principal ideal domain such as $\mathbb Z$ or $F[x]$. However, in the algebra books I can only find forms of the theorem for $F[x]$, but what I need is a reference for $\mathbb Z$. So, is $\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to some polynomial ring $F[x]$? I've tried with $F = \mathbb F_2$, but that doesn't seem to work.

Sorry for this stupid question, but I'm very unexperienced with algebra.

Comment: If you're trying to teach yourself the algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form has an example over $\mathbb{Z}$. If you need to include a reference in a paper, obviously wikipedia is not an ideal source!

Comment: It is not. You can prove separately that $F$ can’t have either positive characteristic or zero characteristic. The proof only needs PID.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. "The proof only needs PID" That's the point. I cannot find any proof in the literature for $\mathbb Z$ (or PID in general). I only find the theorem for $F[x]$. Do you have a reference for me?

Comment: See *Basic Algebra* by Jacobson

Comment: @lhf Thanks. But I cannot find it in there. It only treats Jordan canonical form and rational form.

Comment: Section 3.7 of *Basic Algebra* (second edition) by Jacobson

Comment: @lhf Thank you very much! I found it.